# Swift fix Cannot assign value of type '()?' to type '[ShopData]?'

Tags: arrays, swift, append, alamofire, swifty-json

im stuck resolving my problem for over a week and i dont know how, im junior.

i want to get an array data from the dictionary data which both has the same name in backend = "data",

```
"data": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id_shop": "63ae163a-572a-4807-b5e7-5e8f91d9e18c",
            "name": "What's Next?",
            "slug": "whats-next",
            "address": null,
            "description": null,
            "logo": null
        },
```

**and im write the model in IOS like this:**

```
struct ShopData: {
var id_shop: String?
var name: String?
var slug: String?
var address: String?
var description: String?
var logo: String?

init(response: JSON) {
    id_shop = response["id_shop"].stringValue
    name = response["name"].stringValue
    slug = response["slug"].stringValue
    address = response["address"].stringValue
    description = response["description"].stringValue
    logo = response["logo"].stringValue
    
}
```

**then im doing the method using alamofire and swiftyJson, and the error like this:**

*response is the result response from API

```
if response!["status"].stringValue == "Success" {
                do {
                    let responses = JSON(response!)
                    let data = responses["data"]["data"]
                    shops = try self.shops?.append(ShopData(response: [data]))
                    
                    print(self.shops!)
                    
                } catch {
                    print("the error: \(error)")
                }      
            }
```

method & the error

[image]

error are on the append line, it said:

> Cannot assign value of type '()?' to type '[ShopData]?'

i cant get any source that exactly the same

Comment: As suggested in your previous question, research and implement `Codable` instead.

Comment: The error is telling you that `append()` doesn't return anything so assigning its result to an array of `ShopData` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i've googling for codable but still not found the same problem with me, why you just not tell me the right code or the link source instead?

Comment: @PhillipMills then what i need to do? like what code better then? help me pls

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/119/codable-cheat-sheet, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types, https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/codable/, you research and try yourself then we can help you with that if you ran into an issue

Comment: you mean i need to change the whole networking to use codable or it can just on this issue? @JoakimDanielson, because im success get the data but just cant append json data into my app

Comment: Not the networking, only the json decoding.